# System.IO.Compression in ASP.NET VNext full CLR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to use `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive` in a ASP.NET VNext class library in VS2015 Preview. I added the `System.IO.Compression` package using NuGet, and it added it to my project.json as a aspnetcore50 dependency.

When I try to use the `ZipArchive`, the intellisense says is not available in ASP.NET 5.0 but it is available in ASP.NET Core 5.0. If I switch to use ASP.NET Core using the drop down in the top bar, then my code works as expected, but when I choose normal ASP.NET it doesn't work.

I tried manually adding it as a dependency to aspnet50 in the project.json, but that didn't fix it.

I need to use the full CLR over the Core CLR as I need to load assemblies into the `AppDomain` at run time, and I believe this isn't supported in the Core CLR.

Please could someone explain what's going on here, maybe point me to some articles or blog posts, show me how to fix this.

**Update:**
I guess a better way or wording this is - the `ZipArchive` is not available in aspnet50, but it is available in aspnetcore50 when I add the `System.IO.Compression` NuGet package. Why is this?

Comment: Did you try adding System.IO.Compression as an assembly reference, instead of NuGet? It is part of the default .NET framework installation.

Comment: I'm still learning v5.0, but I don't think you need to do that when targeting the full CLR. I have the namespace available but ZipArchive isn't there, which is why I tried adding it through NuGet, which then only added it to the Core CLR.

Comment: Adding a basic .NET assembly reference is the normal thing to do. NuGet is an extension, you only need that when you add an external reference not present in .NET. Or was it removed from .NET v5?

Comment: Yeh I get that, but the new ASP.NET stuff isn't normal, hence the confusion :) unless I've missed something big - how would I do that in VS2015 with a VNext class library?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They only way that I get the project to compile and work was doing  the following in the project.json. I'm not too familiar with the compression library so I did not spend time trying to compress a file. Below you will a sample code that will compile with no issue.

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {

    },

    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {

            },
            "frameworkAssemblies": {                
                "System.IO.Compression": "4.0.0.0"

            }
        },
        "aspnetcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22231",                
                "System.IO.Compression.ZipFile": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.IO": "4.0.10-beta-22231",
                "System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.0-beta-22231"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Code

```
    public static void ZipFile(string path)
    {
        var data = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
        var zip = new ZipArchive(data, ZipArchiveMode.Create,false);
        zip.CreateEntry(path + ".zip");            
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Look like I was just missing the `"frameworkAssemblies"` from the aspnet50. I didn't know about this. Is this the new way of adding assembly references for assemblies that are part of the framework?

Comment: Hi Tom, I'm not a 100% sure but I think it's the new way now, I have the same problem with httpclient and they way that I solved the issue was adding the core reference  and the framework reference.

Comment: Thank you!!! I must have spent four hours just now trying to add a framework reference in my vNext project. I was getting very discouraged as it should take no more than five seconds, but this answer saved the day!